# Leak Canary Notification not showing.

Tags: android, memory-leaks

```
 package injection.view.mainactivity;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.AsyncTask;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import com.squareup.leakcanary.RefWatcher;
     import javax.inject.Inject;

     import injection.mainactivity.DaggerMainActivityComponent;
     import injection.mainactivity.ExampleApplication;
     import injection.mainactivity.MainActivityComponent;
     import injection.view.AnotherActivity.AnotherActivity;
     import webv.agoel.mvpdagger.R;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
      MainActivityContract.View {


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
@Inject
MainActivityPresenter presenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DaggerMainActivityComponent.create().inject(this);
    presenter.addView(this);
    presenter.doCalculation("hello world");
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = ExampleApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
    refWatcher.watch(this);
}

@Override
public void updateView(String log) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateView: " + log);
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        context = (Context) params[0];

        // Invoke the leak!
        SingletonSavesContext.getInstance().setContext(context);


        return "result";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Intent newActivity = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);
    }
}
```

}

How come the code above does not show the Leak Canary notification on my device?

I did the below steps

1.) Create Singleton that will hold on to a context ( Activity)
2.) Set the Main Activity's context to the Singleton.
3.) Start AnotherActivity causing the memory leak.

However, I don't see any Leak Canary Notification.

Comment: show code SingletonSavesContext.class

Comment: public class SingletonSavesContext {
    private Context context;
    private static SingletonSavesContext instance;

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static SingletonSavesContext getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonSavesContext();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {
private WeakReference<MainActivity> mWeakReference;

public GetDataAsync(MainActivity activity) {
        mWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    MainActivity activity = mWeakReference.get();
    // Invoke the leak!
    SingletonSavesContext.getInstance().setContext(activity);


    return "result";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    MainActivity activity = mWeakReference.get();
    Intent newActivity = new Intent(activity, AnotherActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(newActivity);
}
}
```

in Oncreate()

```
new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
```

Comment: I don't see the leak canary notification